# Getting a 404 when trying to run a qunit test

Tags: sapui5, qunit

I'm using the trial webide and trying to run myqunittest.qunit.html from the /test-resources folder. by using the url /test-resources/myqunittest.qunit.html. However it simply returns a 404 error whenever I attempt to run it.

Is this a problem with defining the resources? I don't understand how, for example, view/Main.view.xml can be found but not anything in the test-resources folder (I've tried just creating a simple js or html file containing a single line and it still 404'd).

I've copied the page directly from the qunit help page, [QUnit Testing Fundamentals](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/70/8002929ea548fd9433954a9275eb5f/content.htm?frameset=/en/a6/b0657d226343da81ad96632cd1bd83/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/e4/843b8c3d05411c83f58033bac7f072/plain.htm&node_id=662), this code seems to imply it should just work without any reference to the rest of the app.

I've tried various combinations of sap.ui.localResources and data-sap-ui-resourceroots in both html files to no avail.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
myapp
    test-resources
        myqunittest.qunit.html
    view
        Main.controller.js
        Main.view.xml
    index.html
```

myqunittest.qunit.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
     type="text/javascript"
     src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
     data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
     data-sap-ui-noConflict="true">
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/qunit.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/qunit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/sap/ui/qunit/qunit-junit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/sap/ui/qunit/QUnitUtils.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

    <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"myapp": "./"}'
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
    </script>

    <script>
            sap.ui.localResources("view");

            var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"idMain"});
            var page = sap.ui.view({id:"idMain", viewName:"myapp.view.Main", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
            app.addPage(page);
            app.placeAt("content");
    </script>

</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAP WebIDE adds neo-app.json to a project you create. It contains this entry:

```
{
    "path": "/test-resources",
    "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/test-resources"
    },
    "description": "SAPUI5 Test Resources"
}
```

This is interfering with creating my own test-resources folder (one doesn't already exist in the project), and was causing the 404 error. Removing this entry has fixed my problem.

Comment: Instead of removing this entry, you can just simply rename your own test-resources to any other name like "tests" and it works flawless again. So keep the neo-app.json untouched and simply change your directory name for the tests.

Answer (score 1):

In your index.html you are loading ui5 relatively to the index.html in a resources folder

so on your server there is another folder

```
myapp
    resources
        sap-ui-core.js
    test-resources
        myqunittest.qunit.html
    view
        Main.controller.js
        Main.view.xml
    index.html
```

The problem is, that you are loading the core also relatively to your test-resources. You probably need to go 1 directory up.

so in myqunittest.qunit.html
change the bootstrap to

```
<script src="../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
```

Best regards,
Tobias

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion hasn't worked. The 404 error seems to suggest it's the actual test-resources folder or the file inside which cannot be found, which I do not understand.